# sqlalchemy different behaviour on different table in same schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

I am connecting to `clickHouse` database by means of `sqlalchemy`. ne table is okay but another one acts weird.

When I print `querystatement`, the table name is loaded twice in it! Can anyone helps me to find out why two different tables might act differently .
My code :

```
session.query(className)
```

query.statement:

```
select a,b from table_name, table_name
```

Comment: can you provide more info like models and tables and the actual real query that is being generated so we can replicate and debug your issue?

Comment: @theemee I don't think that would help at all. i just wanna know posssible problems

Comment: there could be a problem with your table or model definition. So yes, it would help. Otherwise, how can I replicate your error?

Comment: @theemee ,thanks to my coworker, the problem is resolved. it was because of adding primary_key in query.with_entities. removing the id column from this part resolved the problem :)